# What would a term for diminishing of magic, diversity, beauty, and power be?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to figure out what the proper literary term would be for the following description.

In many books and films there is a theme where the world is or was full of magic and beauty and then that age ends and the following is more mundane.

Sometimes this is accompanied due to results of an evil event and other times just from the slow approaching of time.

An evil occurrence example could be something like in
*Star Wars: A New Hope*, when Luke is in Kenobi's little house,

> An elegant weapon for a more civilized 
>   time. For over a thousand generations 
>   the Jedi Knights were the guardians 
>   of peace and justice in the Old 
>   Republic. Before the dark times, 
>   before the Empire.

An example of time could be in The Lord of the Rings at the end of the 3rd age (after the war of the ring). Most of the elves are either leaving or have left, Gandalf leaves, later into the age the Ents become..treeish, and the dwarves vanish from mans knowledge. All that is left is men.

So while Men flourish all the other races diminish. Theres even a scene in the movies where Frodo and Sam spy some wood elves leaving middle earth and Sam says,

> I don't know why, but it makes me sad"

So **my question** is, what would a term for this..diminishing of magic, diversity, beauty, power be?

It's kind of like Nostalgia in a way, not sure what the best term would be..

Comment: It's a good question. One metaphor I like, where we can safely place all these miracles we don't see today, is *the mists of history*. Those mists were everywhere, surrounding, enveloping, and they get thicker the further back you go, preventing even the most piercing gaze from seeing all. They hid secrets and mysteries. So we need a word for the lifting of the mist, its slow but inevitable disappearance, leaving only a few tendrils in odd corners here and there today. But I have no such word, except perhaps *demystification*, in the double entendre sense.

Comment: The term **prelapsarian** (referring to the Fall of Adam in Eve in Genesis) is sometimes used in this sense. It's a bit specific, but can be used metaphorically a bit more widely. Compare also [Ye Goode Olde Days](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YeGoodeOldeDays)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Or a longer period which stretches to a few hundred years later, *antediluvian*.

Comment: Well, that's also a biblical reference, but is it a positive one? I thought it just meant "old" or "long ago", in a pejorative sense; almost the opposite of what OP refers to. Compare [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antediluvian).

Comment: @JoshFriedlander It does mean "long ago" but it itself it has no pejorative tones. It can and has been used pejoratively, but that's context-dependent.

Comment: @Dan Not according to the dictionary definition I linked to.

Comment: If you're free to make up your own words, consider _prosaicization_ or _mundanification_.

Comment: Can you include a sentence showing how you would use this term? That will help clarify whether you want a term for the age of miracles, the post-miraculous era, the passing from one to the other, or the feeling of loss one might feel when looking back on lost wonders. (It's also technically required for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call this form of writing **reminiscence**. The tone is wistful, in that the writer or the character expressing the thought is wishing that things could have gone otherwise.

For example, something that *Star Wars* and *Lord of the Rings* have in common is their use of reminiscence to provide context for the actions of their main characters.

In a stronger and more personal form, you could call it using a flashback, or writing in retrospective style, but reminiscence is more associated with sadness.

Comment: I like this answer, I liked the word decay ...but your answer sounds better!

Answer (score 1):

The term my father would use (to describe the diminution of his own powers from previous heights) is [**decline.**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=decline)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like 'a darkening of times'?
or ' a regressive period' 'regression'